# Boolean value isChecked not changing with foreach

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, android-listview

So I'm trying to select all items from a list with a button that is called select all , now I press the button and what I do is update the **isChecked** variable of all fields to be true, after that I `notifysetDataChange()` so all the items are draw again and checked for me, I also use an interface to notify to my UI the current member list with all members selected

Now, when I press my button

```
 binding.btnSelectAll.setOnClickListener {
           attendanceAdapter.checkAllFields()
        }
```

and update my list in the adapter

```
 fun checkAllFields(){
        memberList.forEach { it.isChecked == true }
        itemClickListener.onAllSelectedMembers(memberList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

All memberList **isChecked** values stays as **false** and not changing, I dont really know why is not changing, the data class of Members has a mutable isChecked variable that can be reasigned and the memberList is also a mutable list that can be changed, why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code snippet you shared for `checkAllFields()`, you are doing a `boolean operation` `==`. You should be doing an assignment operation instead.
Near the line : `memberList.forEach { it.isChecked = true }`

So your code should look like this:

```
fun checkAllFields(){
        memberList.forEach { it.isChecked = true }
        itemClickListener.onAllSelectedMembers(memberList)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

Comment: oops I let that slip in